aggregating MAX() over a group over the MAX() of a subgroup
I have a table of which looks something like:



sport
date
daily_attempt




soccer
11/12/2021
1


soccer
04/09/2023
1


soccer
04/09/2023
2


swimming
07/07/2022
1


swimming
08/08/2024
1


swimming
08/08/2024
2


swimming
08/08/2024
3


hockey
11/12/2021
1


hockey
11/12/2021
2


hockey
03/05/2023
1



For each sport, I want to select get the latest date, and within that date the largest record in daily_attempt. So in the example above I would like the output to be



sport
date
daily_attempt




soccer
04/09/2023
2


swimming
08/08/2024
3


hockey
03/05/2023
1



The obvious way to do this is something like:
SELECT s.sport, s.date, s.MAX(daily_attempt)
FROM table s
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT t.sport, MAX(t.date) max_date
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.sport
) u ON t.sport = u.sport AND s.date = t.max_date
GROUP BY s.sport, s.date

I was really hoping there was a cleaner and/or faster way to do this.
I have a lot of tables like this (some of them truly huge), and in some cases more than just one group and subgroup that I need to do this kind of nested aggregation on.
I was originally thinking something along the lines of
SELECT t.sport, t.date, t.daily_attempt
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM sport s WHERE s.sport = t.sport AND 
   GROUP BY s.sport 
   HAVING t.daily_attempt=MAX(s.daily_attempt) AND t.date = MAX(s.date)
)

But this isn't equivalent.
Is it actually possible to do this in a different way? I had also thought something using GROUP BY CUBE or GROUP BY ROLLUP.

For clarity, to make sure I understand this: in the very first sample row (soccer, 11/12/2021, 1), if the daily attempt value was 3, that would be the max for the soccer group, but you would NOT want that row, because it was from an older date, correct?

@JoelCoehoorn that is correct. That was the intention behind including the Hockey example. It has two daily_attempt records but they are at an earlier date.

Perfect. The existing answer looks correct to me, then. If you're not familiar with Window Functions, this is a good place to start. This greatly over-generalizes, but one distinction for Window Functions vs aggregation is window function can be good for finding whole rows within a group, where aggregation will find values, with results that are not directly related to any specific row.

Use row_number() window function to find each sport's row with its latest date etc.
select sport, date, daily_attempt
from
(
    SELECT sport, date, daily_attempt,
           row_number() over
               (partition by sport order by date desc, daily_attempt desc) rn
    FROM table
) dt
where rn = 1


Accepting this answer, thank you. After some testing this turns out to be faster than what I had. I had thought window functions tended to be much slower, but apparently not.
